# What is the difference between INSERT...RETURNING and pl/pgsql RETURN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

(cross posted to the [pgsql-novice mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20140312164329.GA18712@scruffle.mackler.org))

### Suppose the following:

```
CREATE TABLE base_foo (size int);                                                                              

CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT * FROM base_foo;                                                                     

CREATE FUNCTION insert_foo() RETURNS TRIGGER AS                                                                
$$BEGIN                                                                                                        
  INSERT INTO base_foo VALUES (NEW.size);                                                                      
  RETURN NEW;                                                                                                  
END$$ language plpgsql;                                                                                        

CREATE TRIGGER insert_foo INSTEAD OF INSERT ON foo                                                             
FOR EACH ROW execute PROCEDURE insert_foo();
```

### Observe This Behavior

I can insert into my view:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2);
```

It works; no problem.  Now, if I change the trigger function so
that instead of two statements, the second one `RETURN`, it is rather one
`INSERT` with a `RETURNING` clause, as so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_foo() RETURNS TRIGGER AS                                                     
$$BEGIN                                                                                                        
  INSERT INTO base_foo VALUES (NEW.size)                                                                       
  RETURNING NEW;                                                                                               
END$$ language plpgsql;
```

then an insert causes an error:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3);                                                                                    
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data                                                               
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_foo() line 2 at SQL statement
```

### The Documentation

[Docs say of
RETURN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN58181):

> RETURN with an expression terminates the function *and returns the
>   value* of expression to the caller.

[Docs say of RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-insert.html#AEN78354):

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute *and return
>   value(s)* based on each row actually inserted.

(emphases mine)

### My questions are two:

1. What is the actual difference in meaning
   between these two keywords in this context, explained in a way that
   would permit me to predict the error?
2. What is the meaning of the error, *i.e.*, since the trigger
   function needs a value to return, and since the `INSERT` is the
   final statement of the trigger function, why does the query have no
   destination for the result data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read also this excerpt (from the same link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html)

> If the INSERT command contains a RETURNING clause, the result will be
>   similar to that of a SELECT statement containing the columns and
>   values defined in the RETURNING list, computed over the row(s)
>   inserted by the command.

Yes, I know that this description may be confusing :)

In easy words: returning clause works similar to SELECT, which retrieves rows from the table, combines them into **a resultset**, and sends **this resultset directly to the client** (the client = gui tool, java/c++ programm etc.). The client must know how to read this resultset (open it, retrieve rows, values etc. from it), using some API - for example in java there is JDBC api for processing resultsets--> look for `ResultSet` class.
So, returning clause creates a resultset and sent it to the client - in the same way as ordinary SELECT does.

Return statement in the function terminates that function and returns the value of expression **to the caller.**
Not directly to the client, but to the caller - to the other function/procedure or SELECT statement which called this function. And doesn't returns the resultset (a set of rows), but the value.